# Saving Tweets For Current User / Authorized User into Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working on a small project and I'm a little stuck. I've follow a few tutorials online to get things moving and here is what I came up with. Everything works when it comes to authenticating with Twitter and using the Twitter gem to run something like;

```
current_user.twitter.home_timeline(count:10)
```

However, since Twitter has limits, I decided that the "current_user" that is authenticated with Omniauth, his/her tweets would be saved into the Database related to that user by User_id. Here's what I've got so far;

CONTROLLER:

```
def pull
current_user.newtweets.pull_tweets
end
```

MODEL (tweets.rb)

```
class Newtweets < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :followers, :retweets, :screen_name, :time_date, :tweet_id,
:user_id

belongs_to :user

def self.pull_tweets
Twitter.home_timeline(since_id: maximum(:tweet_id)).each do |tweet|
unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
    create!(
            tweet_id: tweet.id,
            followers: tweet.user.followers_count,
            retweets: tweet.retweet_count,
            time_date: tweet.created_at,
            content: tweet.text,
            screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name,
    )
end
end
end
```

MODEL(user.rb)

```
...
has_many :newtweets
...
```

ROUTE:

```
match 'refresh' => 'tweet#pull'
```

So, I'm new at this, but that is what I've constructed so far. I do get an error with the setup above; "uninitialized constant User::Newtweet"

Now, if I go to the Controller and replace the following line in the Controller;
    def pull
    current_user.newtweets.pull_tweets.limit(100)
    end

with;

```
def pull
Newtweets.pull_tweets
end
```

I get another error; Could not authenticate you

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, or so I think but I'm sure its not the cleanest approach but it works for what I need. Here it is;

```
def self.pull
    tweets = User.current.twitter.home_timeline(since_id: maximum(:tweet_id))
    tweets.each do |tweet|
        unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
        Newtweets.create({tweet_id: tweet.id, followers: tweet.user.followers_count, retweets: tweet.retweet_count, time_date: tweet.created_at, content: tweet.text, screen_name: tweet.user.screen_name, user_id: User.current })
        end
   end
end
```